# Tap Gesture on tableViewCell Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I would like to complete an action when the image in the table view cell is taped. I set a tap gesture through the storyboard but it reads the tap everytime the cell is touched.

How can I Complete a tap gesture when only the image in my table view cell is taped?

[image]

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return generalRoomDataArr.count // your number of cell here
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        //Transform Data From ^ to load at the bottom
        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
        cell?.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
        cell?.accessoryView?.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);

        //Set username label to display username
        let usernameLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        usernameLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].username


        //Set message label to display message
        let messageLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        messageLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].message
        messageLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        //initialize UI Profile Image
        let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

        //Make Porfile Image Cirlce
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true

        //Set timeStampLabel to current time AGO
        let timeStampLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
        timeStampLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].timeStamp
        timeStampLabel.numberOfLines = 0


        //Loading and change of Usesrs profile image on chat cell
        let userProfileChatImage = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].photoURL

        //Load profile image(on cell) with URL & Alamofire Library



            let downloadURL = NSURL(string: userProfileChatImage!)
            imageView.af_setImage(withURL: downloadURL as! URL)






        // your cell coding
        return cell!
    }






    @IBAction func userPhotoTaped(_ sender: Any) {

        print("tapped")
    }








}//END CLASS
```

I have also tried this

```
let tapped:UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("TappedOnImage:")))
        tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        cell?.imageView?.addGestureRecognizer(tapped)

func TappedOnImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        print("Elltappy")
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use like this. Create a custom cell and must use isUserInteractionEnabled for image view and you can handle image tapped or table view did select action.

```
class TestCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageV: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // You must to use interaction enabled
    imageV.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageV.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(_:))))
}

func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("image tapped")
} }
```

Comment: I knew there was a better way to do this. You are the best @Halil İbrahim YILMAZ

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a `UIButton` instead of an image view? You can remove the default text and replace it with the profile image in the storyboard, or programmatically `button.setImage(image, for: .normal)`. This way you'll be able to connect the button to you `IBAction` in your custom cell class to the touchUpInside event of the button.

***UPDATE***

```
//initialize UI Profile Image
let profileImageButton = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIButton

//Make Porfile Image Button Cirlce
profileImageButton.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageButton.frame.size.width/2
profileImageButton.clipsToBounds = true

profileImageButton.addTarget(self, selector: #selector(userPhotoTaped), action: .touchUpInside)

// ...

profileImageButton.imageView?.af_setImage(withURL: downloadURL as! URL)
```

Comment: No that will not work for me the way my class is set up any other ideas?

Comment: Ah I see you're retrieving outlets using viewWithTag, but that's fine. You can still replace the image view with a button and connect the button to your `IBAction` programmatically.

Comment: I have a firebase dataBase loading my images and I dont want to change how my images are loaded i just need to read when the ImageView in my tableviewcell is tapped.

Comment: You won't need to change the way you download your images. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Can you show me an example so i better understand then.

Comment: how do i set up the profileImage button? Are you saying overlay the button over the image?

Comment: You overlay the image view with a button and have the same effect but it would be cleaner to simply replace the image view with a button, same size, same position, and then set the image of the button to the profile image. Also give it a tag of 3 and then replace the code you have with the code in my answer.

Comment: I feel that there is a more effective way to do this?

Comment: By using a button of type `.system`, you get some feedback when you press and hold it (the button dims a little to show it's being touched). However, if you prefer, you can simply overlay the image view with a button and only use the `addTarget` line of my answer.

Comment: Can you show me in swift3 im getting an error for your example

Comment: My mistake, it should be `.touchUpInside`, not `.didTouchUpInside`

Comment: use `.touchUpInside`

Comment: still has no member of .touchUpInside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141479/discussion-between-callam-and-codechicksrock).

Comment: Isnt adding a button over the image enough ? Rather than removing the image and adding the button, and then setting image to button.

Comment: Yes that can work too however in my opinion, it would be cleaner to use just the `UIButton` and set the image of the button to the profile image.